# Get file Versions in ITHit WebDav Server Engine Library using AJAX Browser in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, ajax, version, webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I am working on ITHit WebDav Server Engine Library in ASP.NET, I have successfully deployed the Delta V server and able to get all version history in database of each file. But I am unable to use those versions like moving back to previous versions or even reading those version details from properties. For this purpose I even tried using AJAX Browser but the versions are shown as Undefined. I really need help for version controlling of my documents, where I can successfully choose versions from front end and my document goes back to previous versions